# Arrays In loops by C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I want to make a lot of array in for loops by C# like below: please help me!

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    int[][] a+i=new int[10][3];
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to understand why you are trying to create these arrays

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do

Comment: Can you please show what the arrays would look like when you are done? Your syntax looks a bit like C++ pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Can you reformulate your question? What do you mean with "male a lot of array"? Besides, ´int[][] a+i=new int[10][3];´ is far from being c# correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, best will be to use a [`Dictionary<string,int[][]>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

During creation you will place a new array (which you just created) and assosiate it to the key `"a" + i`.

To get this array, just get the value attached to the relevant key.

Something like (C#-like pseudo code):

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,int[][]>();
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    var temp = new int[10][3];
    map["a" + i] = temp
}
```

and to get a value just use `map[key]` (for example `map["a7"]` will get the 7th element).

---

A good alternative would be to use a 3D array.

Comment: thanks; it's a good answer but it has error

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to create [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). Here's how you can do it:

```
var a = new int[10][];
for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    a[i] = new int[3];

for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < a[i].Length; j++)
        a[i][j] = 1;  // Initialize with your values
```

Comment: Thanks. it's good but that isn't my answer